# Selenium-Flex API sample problem

Tags: apache-flex, selenium, flexbuilder, selenium-ide

I'm trying the [sample demo](http://sfapi.googlecode.com/files/sfapi-sample.zip) of selenium [flex API](http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/). After following the instructions on the main page for compiling the project with sfpi.swc and taking the generated selben.swf in bin directory and trying to run some test(assertFlexText) using Selenium IDE, I get the following error:

```
[error] Function getFlexText not found on the External Interface for
the flash object selben
```

I have tried several other flex tests and got error messages similar to the one mentioned above.

For some reason I believe that the generated selben.swf  through the automatic build of project in flex builder is not the desired one, though it didn't indicate any build problem after including sfpi.swc.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use SeleniumFlex Api and SeleniumIde for my projecy with excellent result BUT using my own version of each of one. Your error maybe is for not include the lib of SeleniumFlexApi in the compile time( -include-libraries "libs\SeleniumFlexAPI.swc" ).

After that u can enable capture and replay with SeleniumIde change the main source (read this [post](http://schneide.wordpress.com/2009/06/04/enable-capturereplay-for-selenium-flex/)) and use the user-extensions.js (in the SeleniumFlexApi project) with the SeleniumIde user option. Its really easy.

With these change u can capture and replay in firefox (v 3.06 or minor) and after that, if u use java, u can use Flex-UI-Selenium, Flash-Selenium for ur integration test with SeleniumRC.

I hope this information be usefull. I u have any question let me know.

Comment: I kinda did everything possible to run version 0.2.6 of the API http://code.google.com/p/sfapi/ but I couldn't manage it.....

Comment: Im talking about this selenium flex api http://sourceforge.net/projects/seleniumflexapi/ without automation framework.